# Expanding bootstrap accordian groups all at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap collapse element. When I expand one accordian group, the other closes. What should do If i dont want the other accordian to close when one if clicked?

```
<div class='accordion-group'>" + "<div class='accordion-heading' style='font-size:15px;'>" + "<a class='accordion-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion1' href="#collapse1">
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is from the bootstrap website on how to do this.

> Just add data-toggle="collapse" and a data-target to element to automatically assign control of a collapsible element. The data-target attribute accepts a css selector to apply the collapse to. Be sure to add the class collapse to the collapsible element. If you'd like it to default open, add the additional class in.

Here is example code.

The big difference, is adding `data-target="#collapseOne"` instead of `data-parent="#accordion"`.

```
<div class="accordion-group">
   <div class="accordion-heading">
       <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" href="#">
          Item #1
       </a>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseOne" class=" collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about data-target and data-parent :) But just this doesnt work. I added data-target instead of data-parent but id of the inner accordian element also needs to be given in href attribute.Then, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<div class='accordion-group'><div class='accordion-heading' style='font-size:15px;'><a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target="#collapse1" href='#collapse1'>

TEXT
</a></div>
<div id="collapse1" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px "><div class="accordion-inner">
TEXT_INNER
</div></div></div>
```